# Which application.yml that're in src/main/resources and src/test/resources directories will be used when testing

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven-3

In a spring boot Maven project, there's a `application.yml` file in `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources` respectively.

When running test cases, it seems that testing will only use the file in `src/test/resources` directory.It won't load two files and override the properties in `src/main/resources/application.yml`.
And if there isn't the file in `src/test/resources` directory, it will use the file in `src/main/resources` directory.

How does spring boot to load the `application.yml` file in these two directories? What're the rules? or What does this action depend on?
Where can I look up more information about this online?

[**Example:**](https://github.com/niaomingjian/Spring-boot-workspace/tree/develop/spring-boot-main-test-application-yaml)

```
└───spring-boot-main-test-application-yaml
    ├───pom.xml
    └───src
        ├───main
        │   ├───java
        │   ├───resources
        │       ├───application.yml
        │   
        ├───test
            ├───java
            ├───resources
                └─── application.yml
```

`src/main/resource/application.yml`

```
name: Phil(main)
sample:
  name: Andy(main)
```

`src/test/resource/application.yml`

```
name: Phil(test)
sample:
  name: Andy(test)
```

case1: `src/main/resource/application.yml` exists
output: Hello Phil(main),Andy(main)

case2: `src/main/resource/application.yml` and `src/test/resource/application.yml` both exist
output: Hello Phil(test),Andy(test)

case3: `src/main/resource/application.yml` and `src/test/resource/application.yml` both exist and comment out `name` in `src/test/resource/application.yml`
output:
`Error - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'name' in value "${name}"`

It seems that this test didn't read properties from `src/main/resource/application.yml` so it couldn't find out `name` property.

Answer (score 0):

Spring detects those two directories and like you said it's figuring out which configs to use based on presence and priority. If you wanted spring to use a particular setting you should define `spring profiles` which can have specialized settings as well as extend default settings.

Comment: Where could I find out the loading rules about this topic online(official explanation)?

Comment: The spring documentation page?

Answer (score 0):

I am working with yml file and make sure that these property files are loaded when the app is build, it is preferred to have the following config in pom.xml

```
<build>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.yml</include>
                    <include>**/*.jks</include>

                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
 ....
</build>
```

Make sure to run the build  (if required start from scratch like deleting the repository folder inside .m2 - This might not be needed at all) Now check the `target/classes` and that should contain the files of all the specified types